# Ingesting SQL Server Logs into Azure Sentinel

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sentinel

I have been following the guide below and have set up the auditing from the two SQL server boxes. I don't understand how to do the Sentinel part as our Sentinel doesn't have the options shown in the second screen shot from the web page.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/monitoring-sql-server-with-azure-sentinel/ba-p/1502960

The workspace is set on basic and to capture all events. In Sentinel, I can only see system events when I query the logs. From the SQL server instances the logs are visible both in Management Studio and the Application Log of event viewer.

Is there now a different configuration which needs to be done in Sentinel?

Comment: Have you followed that article's embedded links to setup "the Azure Sentinel Security Event Connector to collect the logs from the SQL Server system using the MMA Agent"? Your workspace is basic, but the screenshot you refer to is in advanced settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/data-connectors-reference#windows-security-events-via-ama  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/data-connectors-reference#azure-sql-databases